# Have blank cell for formula answer if no data in origianl cell

Tags: worksheet-function, cells

I have a long formula showing if an invoice is paid, late or outstanding.

=IF(K26="",IF(J26

Can I do anything so that when I copy this down my Excel page, if I have no invoices listed it shows a blank cell instead of Late?

Comment: Hi Richard, you will need to create a reproducible problem so others can better help you. At least share sufficient data from your spreadsheet, so that someone else can reproduce the effect of "blank cell instead of Late". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you use Excel Tables, there is no need to pre-fill formulas down empty rows. With an Excel Table, which is created with **Insert > Table**, all formulas and formatting are automatically applied to new rows that are added to the table.

With the pre-filling approach, you can use a formula along these lines:

```
=if(<condition for paid>,"paid",if(<condition for outstanding>,"outstanding",if(<condition for late>,"late","")))
```

In words: if the condition for "paid" is met, return "paid", else, if the condition for "outstanding" is met, return "outstanding", else, if the condition for "late" is met, return "late", else return a blank.

You can also use an IF statement that first checks if a key cell in the row has a value and if not, return a blank. For example, return a blank if the cell in column A of the current row is empty.

```
=if(isblank(A1),"",if(<condition for paid>),"paid",if(<condition for outstanding>,"outstanding",if(<condition for late>,"late",""))))
```